# Filtering and finding duplicates in an observablecollection WPF

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Bit new to this, Is there a way of searching for duplicates in an observablecollection? Basically this is my code:

```
class Player {
    string FirstName;
    string SurName;
    string Group;
}

private ObservableCollection<MyObj>collection;
```

Basically a player can belong to multiple groups, so the player can occur multiple times in
the collection: eg john doe football, john doe baseball, john doe surfing.

What I want to achieve is to filter it to show one player with comma separated groups as group, like this: john doe "football, baseball, surfing"

Extra info: the observable collection is filled up by doing a wcf call (exec a stored proc on the db and getting the results)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing this with a Linq-query using the GroupBy operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the grouping done by looking at a LAMBDA expression e.g.

```
var grouping = MyCollection.GroupBy(x => new { x.FirstName, x.SurName})
                 .Select(group => new {group.Key, group});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suppose that your class is a public one and all your private string fields (as it comes from your code sample) are public properties in reality (tell me if I am wrong!). 
So, your class is something like:

```
    public class Player
    {
        public string FirstName{get; set;}
        public string SurName{get; set;}
        public string Group{get; set;}
    }
```

And the content is similar to:

```
    public static ObservableCollection<Player> collection = new ObservableCollection<Player>
        { new Player{FirstName ="Alexander", SurName="Davidof", Group = "Football"},
        new Player{FirstName ="Alexander", SurName="Davidof", Group = "Baseball"},
        new Player{FirstName ="Alexander", SurName="Medvedev" , Group = "Karate"},
        new Player{FirstName ="Alexander", SurName="Medvedev", Group = "Polo"}};
```

Use LINQ to group your entries by player names and String.Join() to concatenate them into a singles string

```
        var pl = from player in collection
                 group player by new { First = player.FirstName, Second = player.SurName } into gr
                 select String.Format("{0} {1} : {2}", gr.Key.First, gr.Key.Second, String.Join(",", gr.Select( a=> a.Group)));
```

If you print this array

```
        pl.ToList().ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

you'll see something like:

```
Alexander Davidof : Football,Baseball
Alexander Medvedev : Karate,Polo
```